# How to render json in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to move the below logic to somewhere else so I can use it both in my controller and in a rake task.

My controller action looks something like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  @account = # load account
  @sales = # load sales
  ..

  render :json => {
     "user": user,
     "account": @account.map do |a|
        JSON.parse(a.to_json(include: :addresses))
      end,
      "sales": @sales.map do |s| 
        JSON.parse(s.to_json(include: :products))
      end
  }
end
```

Basically the point is that I have to traverse the associations so the JSON has all of the data in it.

How can I move this logic somewhere else so I can then call it in my controller action and also in a rake task.

Comment: one idea is; you create a `table-less model` [its a normal Ruby class] opening an api doing this job. Then you can call it from anywhere

Comment: You can override [as_json](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/as_json) method into user model, and then call it from controller as well as from rake task.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the code to a [presenter](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-09-09-better-ruby-presenters) or use [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), so that the controller and the Rake task call this new class.

```
class UserPresenter
  def initialize(user, account, sales)
    @user = user
    @account = account
    @sales = sales
  end

  def as_json(*)
    {
     "user": @user,
     "account": @account.map do |a|
        JSON.parse(a.to_json(include: :addresses))
      end,  # or @account.as_json(include: :addresses))
     "sales": @sales.map do |s| 
        JSON.parse(s.to_json(include: :products))
      end  # or @sales.as_json(include: :products))
    }
  end
end

# In the controller
render json: UserPresenter.new(@user, @account, @sales)
```

Comment: Isn't the render method doing some work behind the scenes?  Not sure how I can refactor it out.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've had success by passing it a Hash and it converts it to JSON.